# Is it possible to integrate bugzilla with selenium web driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation

Is it possible for us to integrate selenium web driver test with Bugzilla?

My intention are as below:

If we can integrate web driver with Bugzilla,

- can we automatically attach screen shot of failed tests?
- can we record/save the steps that made the bug?

Comment: What language are you using to drive the selenium tests?

Comment: Well u can automate Bugzilla Web UI using selenium webdriver...that way u can integrate ur tests and their results with Bug zilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research I came upon a solution.That is J2Buzilla which is worth for my requirement.
you can explore it [here](https://code.google.com/p/j2bugzilla/.)

Also using webdriver i got solution to get screen shot of bug using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why this couldn't be done if you have a code driven Selenium test suite.  You would need to implement a method run on test failure that adds a bug to Bugzilla using their HTTP REST API.

For the first step, if you are using Java, see this answer on taking a [screenshot when selenium fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429793/can-selenium-take-a-screenshot-on-test-failure) and the referenced [blog post](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2012/01/24/grabbing-screenshots-of-failed-selenium-tests/).  You need to similarily create a new rule, except this time to add a bug to Bugzilla (and hopefully any useful information, logging, that would help you make it useful).

Then here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751635/how-to-post-a-bug-using-bugzilla-rest-api) and link to the [Bugzilla REST API Docs](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API:Methods#Create_new_bug_.28.2Fbug_POST.29) on how to file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something on this lines. Here is the link for the same http://jitendrajogeshwar.wordpress.com/

Comment: Could you please describe what you did here? There's no guarantee your link will still be around a few years from now.

Comment: The is working fine and it has been recently updated by me. I have tried to explain in details about how I went about it